# Create data frame based on rows, which columns meet a certain condition PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a new data frame only using certain rows, which the value of a specific column meets a condition.

I have the following data frame (called: result):

```
source  target weight
     0       0   0.00
     5       1   5.00
     6       2   7.00
     8       3   8.00
     1       4   0.00
     3       5   0.00
     6       6   4.00
     4       7   0.00
```

and I need to get something like this:

```
source  target weight
     5       1   5.00
     6       2   7.00
     8       3   8.00
     6       6   4.00
```

However, I've been using the following procedures but they don't work and I'm getting the same result (first one) over and over.

```
result1 = result[result['weight'] > 0 ]
```

or

```
result1 = result.loc[result['weight'] > 0 ]
```

Comment: what are the `dtype`s here? edit your question with the output from `df.info()`

Answer (score 1):

Credit @EdChum

Most certainly, your weight columns is `str` and in that comparison all your strings are `>` 0.  Turn them to `float`, `int`, or something numeric and problem solved.

#### Hightlight (do this)

```
result1 = results[result['weight'].astype(float) > 0]
```

#### Explanation

#### Setup 1 (Problem)

```
text = """source  target weight
     0       0   0.00
     5       1   5.00
     6       2   7.00
     8       3   8.00
     1       4   0.00
     3       5   0.00
     6       6   4.00
     4       7   0.00"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=1, dtype=str)
#                                                    ^^^^^^^^^
#                                               Create Problem

print df[df.weight > 0]
```

Looks like:

```
  source target weight
0      0      0   0.00
1      5      1   5.00
2      6      2   7.00
3      8      3   8.00
4      1      4   0.00
5      3      5   0.00
6      6      6   4.00
7      4      7   0.00
```

#### Setup 2 (Solution)

```
text = """source  target weight
     0       0   0.00
     5       1   5.00
     6       2   7.00
     8       3   8.00
     1       4   0.00
     3       5   0.00
     6       6   4.00
     4       7   0.00"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=1, dtype=float)
#                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
#                                                    Fix Problem

print df[df.weight > 0]
```

Looks like:

```
   source  target  weight
1     5.0     1.0     5.0
2     6.0     2.0     7.0
3     8.0     3.0     8.0
6     6.0     6.0     4.0
```

For your situation, do this:

```
result1 = results[result['weight'].astype(float) > 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just removing zero?  If so you can use:

```
df.loc[~(df==0).all(axis=1)]
```